# doesn't python uses copy by reference?why is the following code not working then?

Tags: python

```
class x:
    def __init__(self):
        self.y=None
        self.sillyFunc(self.y)
    def sillyFunc(self,argument):
        if argument is None:
            argument='my_name_as_argument'
        self.printy()
    def printy(self):
        print self.y
```

According to me the above code should print >my_name_as_argument,where am i going wrong?

Comment: Python uses call-by-sharing, which *never* changes what references point to.  This makes mutable and immuntable objects appear to be treated differently, although they're really not.  In your case, you're only assigning 'my_name_as_argument' to the local variable `argument` - you never do anything that would change the value of `self.y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python everything is an object and variables contain references to objects. When you make a function call it makes **copies** of the references. Some people including [Guido van Rossum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum)  call this "Call by object reference". [Important note](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Data_structures) from Wikipedia:

> a function cannot change the value a variable references in its calling function.

The code as you posted it prints nothing at all. I think you mean to add this extra line to your program:

```
x()
```

This then results in the output: `None`. This is not surprising because you are printing the value of `self.y` but the only value you ever assign to `self.y` is `None`.

In Python, strings are immutable. Reassigning the value of `argument` only overwrites the local copy of the reference. It does not modify the original string.

As you asked in a comment, if you use a mutable object and you reassign the reference, again this doesn't do what you want - the original object is not affected. If you want to mutate a mutable object you can call a method that mutates it. Simply reassigning a reference does not change the original object.

If you want `self.y` to point to a new object then you have to assign the object reference directly to `self.y`.

Comment: lets say i am not using string ,rather i assign some object to argument as in argument=Some_class() even then its not working

Comment: this mechanism is often called “copy by reference”, AFAIR even in some text books (but I can’t provide a reference now).

Comment: @Konrad: Interesting. I have updated my post to make the first paragraph clearer.

Comment: Python's model is called *call by sharing* - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing.

Answer (score 5):

The assigment

```
argument='my_name_as_argument'
```

only affects the local variable `argument`. It doesn't change what `self.y` points to.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on if you are changing the referenced object itself (and if this object is mutable) or replacing the reference to another object. See the following example, which uses a mutable list...

```
>>> def test(arg):
...     arg.append(123)
...     
... 
>>> s = []
>>> print s
[]
>>> test(s)
>>> print s
[123]
```